# Wix delete a single value in multiString registry key while uninstall

Tags: windows, installation, wix

My installer has to append a value to an existing multistring registry key (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\Notification Packages):

```
<RegistryKey Id='RegistryEntry' Root='HKLM' Key='SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa' Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
    <RegistryValue Type='multiString' Name='Notification Packages' Value='p1' Action='append'/>
</RegistryKey>
```

Problem is that, when uninstalling, it is removing the whole key : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA ie. all values under LSA are deleted, is there any way that i can just delete the value i appended (only p1) and retain the existing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for WiX's [`<RegistryKey>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrykey.htm) element says (emphasis mine):

> *createAndRemoveOnUninstall*
>
> Creates the key, if absent, when the parent component is installed
>   then remove the key with all its values and subkeys when the parent
>   component is uninstalled. Note that this value is useful only if your
>   program creates additional values or subkeys under this key and you
>   want an uninstall to remove them. **MSI already removes all values and
>   subkeys that it creates, so this option just adds additional overhead
>   to uninstall**.

[Additional evidence](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH40119) suggests that the behavior described above applies to multi-string values: the installer engine will automatically remove the appended values on uninstall, preserving the values that were present before the installation.

Therefore, using `create` instead of `createAndRemoveOnUninstall` should do what you want:

```
<RegistryKey Id="RegistryEntry" Root="HKLM"
             Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa"
             Action="create">
    <RegistryValue Type="multiString" Name="Notification Packages"
                   Value="p1" Action="append" />
</RegistryKey>
```